# Redirect Domain Only Without Rest of Url

Tags: php, redirect

Hi I have A Website And I want To Make A Short Domain For It That Only Changes The Domain for Example :

I Want This To Redirect This :  ***http://ex.com/folder/index.php*** To This ***http://example.com/folder/index.php***

Does Anyone Know How To Do That In PHP Or With **.htaccess**

Comment: on your localmchine or on the real internet? First of all, clarify your question, you make me think you try to redirect every access on ex.com route to example.com. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank You For Your Comment  @Soundz And Yes You Are Correct, I Want To Redirect Every Access To ex.com, To example.com But The Rest Of The Url stays The Same

Comment: Please learn how to correctly capitalize (hint: not every word is capitalized).

Answer (score 1):

Using `.htacces`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ex.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</IfModule>
```

In the .htaccess file in the base www folder of the ex.com htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

U need to edit one text file if you want to do in your local host.

sudo geany /etc/hosts;

then add your name along with ip address.
You may do same thing on server side, too.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</IfModule>
```

but be sure to add this in the .htaccess of the ex.com server...